# Java database interaction pattern

Tags: java, jdbc, lambda, java-8, try-with-resources

I am building essentially a java app to handle and respond to RPC events.  I am finding myself doing something along the lines of the following all the time and my java knowledge is hitting a brick wall.

```
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        try {
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(removeFollowersStmt);
            preparedStatement.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(conversation) );
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, Long.parseLong(userId) );
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                assert preparedStatement != null;
                preparedStatement.clearParameters();
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Ideally I would only do the try/catch/finally a single time and be able some how invoke the various database interactions from within the try.

I am not familiar enough with java to do this but my thought was possibly I could create a function that accepted a closure which would be invoked inside the try?

Comment: And what is exactly your problem?

Comment: I am repeating try/catch/finally in every function I would like to only have to do that a single time if at all possible.

Comment: since it is not good close the connection anywhere else in the code other than the finally block, and since the connection close will raise an exception that you want to handle, you are left with no other choice but to have 2 try/catch blocks.

Comment: Calling `clearParameters` before a close doesn't make sense, your `assert` doesn't make sense either: `preparedStatement` could be null here!. Please use `try`-with-resources instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've discovered that proper exception handling for things that need to be closed, like a JDBC `Statement`, is a real pain. Java 8 lambdas might be able to help here, but this is a textbook example for the [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) that was introduced in Java 7. In fact, that tutorial has a JDBC example, though one that's a bit different from what you're trying to do here.

Before we can apply try-with-resources, we need to take a closer look at your `finally` block. First, the assertion that `preparedStatement != null` is actually incorrect at this point. The `conn.prepareStatement` statement at the top of the try-block can throw `SQLException` before `preparedStatement` is assigned, so it might actually still be null by the time the finally-block executes. (Most people add a null check here and only close the statement if it's non-null.) The try-with-resources statement avoids this issue by initializing the resource *outside* the try-finally statement whose finally-block is responsible for closing the resource.

Second, there is a call to `clearParameters` after the assertion. I don't think this is necessary. The statement is about to be closed, and the `preparedStatement` variable is about to go out of scope, so it'll become unreachable and therefore be garbage collected. Clearing the parameters shouldn't really have any effect.

With these points in mind, it becomes clear that the primary responsibility of the finally-block is to close the statement, handle any `SQLException` from the close operation, allowing the enclosing method to return normally. This is pretty much what try-with-resources does.

Rewriting the code to use try-with-resources gives the following:

```
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(removeFollowersStmt)) {
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(conversation) );
        preparedStatement.setLong(2, Long.parseLong(userId) );
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

That's right, the entire finally-block can be dropped! The exact behavior is somewhat different from your original code, though. The differences are in what happens if everything through `executeUpdate` succeeds, but closing the statement throws a `SQLException`. In the original code, a stack trace would be printed and the method would return `true`.

In the revised code, the exception from the `close` call would be caught by the single catch-clause here, which would print the stack trace and return `false`. I don't know whether this is the right thing. My impression is that if closing a statement threw an exception, it might mean that the previously executed update didn't actually succeed. If so, then returning `false` is the right thing here. (But I'm not a JDBC expert.)

This is better than before, but there's still the try-catch boilerplate you have to add around every statement execution. Can you reuse this structure and pass in a lambda? I think so, but we have to do a bit of preparation first. The method will need to take a SQL string that's used to create the `PreparedStatement`, and a lambda that's responsible for setting parameters into the statement. The catch here is that the setters for `PreparedStatement` all can throw `SQLException`. None of the built-in functional interfaces in Java 8's `java.util.function` package deal with this, so we have to create our own functional interface:

```
interface StatementPreparer {
    void prepare(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException;
}
```

Now that we have this, let's write a method that prepares a statement and executes it, handling exceptions, and returning a boolean status:

```
boolean update(String sql, StatementPreparer sp) {
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        sp.prepare(preparedStatement);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now in the code that wants to perform the actual work, it can issue a call something like this:

```
boolean result = update("delete from followers where conv = ? and userid = ?",
    preparedStatement -> {
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(conversation) );
        preparedStatement.setLong(2, Long.parseLong(userId) );
    });
```

Comment: I am interacting with a postgres db, and I am trying to maintain a single connection.  It might have been something I was doing wrong else where but what I found was if I didn't call clearParameters, then the next time I would call conn.prepareStatement(sql) even when setting new parameters it would execute with the parameters set the first time around.  I am going to experiment with both of these solutions.  My java chops are fairly antiquated so thanks for the patience in explaining.

Comment: @Vinnyt Hm, that's odd behavior, JDBC allows drivers to have lots of strange behaviors. If this is still a problem, you could first two lines of the try-block in my example (the calls to `sp.prepare` and `executeUpdate`) in a nested try statement, with a finally-clause that clears parameters. Kind of ugly but at least you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is a web application because of the word "Followers". The following would apply to standalone applications, too, but would be a little different.

There are two conceptual problems with your code which makes your life harder than it needs to be:

**1. You are trying to handle the exceptions in the wrong place.**

If you find yourself writing code like:

```
try {
    doSomething()
} catch( SomeException e ){
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

then something is wrong with the "Layout" of your program. You will be far better of if you move your exception handling to somewhere up the calling chain.

In case this is a web application do it in the servlet. So in your case this would be:

```
void executeMyStatements throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(removeFollowersStmt))
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(conversation) );
        preparedStatement.setLong(2, Long.parseLong(userId) );
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }
    return true;
}
```

and somewhere in

```
MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    void doGet( ... ){

        try {
             executeMyStatements()
             doSomeMoreStuff()
             executeMyOtherStatements()

        } catch( Throwable t ){

             doSomethingMeaningfullWithException( t );
             // e.g. t.printStackTrace( response.getOutputStream() );
             // logger.error( t ); ...
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Use Transactions**

(Perhaps you're doing this anyway but in case not)

Transactions will help you. Are you really sure it makes sence to proceed with the next statement if the previous one failed with an exception which you caught? Or is your database in a state where you where better off starting over with what you wanted to do?

This fits nicely with the approach of handling the exception elsewhere. What you basically want to do is this: (**Pseudocode**)

```
try{ 
    Connection con = createConnectionSomehow();
    Transaction transaction = con.startTransactionSomehow();

    executeSomeStatements();
    doStuff()
    doDeeperStuffWithMoreStatementsWhichCallOtherStatementsDeepBelowInMoria();

} catch( Exception t ){

    transaction.rollback();
    doSomethingUsefullWith( t );

} finally {

    transactions.commit();
    connection.close()
}
```

You will have to wrap some statements in the `finally` with `if != null` which I omitted in order to show the main concept more clearly and this shouldn't be to hard.

Oh, and by the way: You're using `parseLong` in creation of your statement. This *will fail* some day or another with a `NumberFormatException` which is a `RuntimeException` which needs not to be caught. In your approach you are only handling the SQLException so the other one will propagate up and (in the worst case in a standalone app) will crash the app. If you use my approach this exception is caught by `catch( Throwable t )` and will be handled gracefully.

Organizing your code in the proposed way will make your life a lot easier and avoids the code repetitions you didn't like while improving the general code quality and stability. And it will give you better error handling in case something goes wrong.